# Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, Faulting module name: jvm.dll, version: 25.71.0.1

Tags: web8.5

We receive a random error in the Event viewer with `Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384`,

[image]

The detailed error message is below

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: jvm.dll, version: 25.71.0.1, time stamp: 0x5a39cc1f
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000015e712
Faulting process id: 0xff4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d399074d32b5a3
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161\bin\server\jvm.dll
Report Id: 5cd48e58-04fb-11e8-80cf-02c445cb545e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Our web application is based on SDL Web 8.5 and ASP.NET. Is there any chance that the error might be due to the interaction of SDL Web 8.5 jars present in the web application with the JDK?

Please help.

Comment: If you’re on 8.5, why do you use the JVM? Do you need any of the legacy functionality that’s not available with the web services?

Comment: does this error occur when you start the web application, or when you call a certain broker functionality?

Comment: i'm not sure if it's related or not (as the q/a i'm referring to is not tridion specific), but can you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282249/iis-app-pool-crashing-with-exception-0xc0000005. Could it be a permissions problem ?

Comment: @HaraldHoffelinck : We are not able pick the scenario for which the scenario occurs.It is logged once in every 3 to 4 days.

Comment: Since you are using ASP.NET web farm application with CD legacy in process stuffs config and jars in the bin, double check the DLLs (xmogrt.dll, TridionContentDelivery.dll) and jars used 64bit vs 32bit based on your setup. Also, double check the prerequisites versions (Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64))

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a StackOverflow Exception, which is caused by unbounded recursion (a function repeatedly calling itself, etc). This can't be caught by regular try/catch block. You can track the problem down using DebugDiag and WinDbg.

DebugDiag can be configured to generate a crash dump when the StackOverflowException occurs. Download a https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49924.

1. Open DebugDiag and click Add Rule.
2. "Crash" should already be selected. Click Next.
3. Choose "A specific IIS web application pool" and click Next.
4. Select the application pool and click Next.
5. You should be on the Advanced Configuration Window. Click Exceptions under Advanced Settings.
6. Click Add Exception and choose Stack Overflow, with an Action Type of Full Userdump
7. Click OK and save and close out.

Next time a StackOverflowException occurs, you'll have a crash dump. Now to need to interpret the dump file.

Debugging tools for Windows is part of the Windows SDK and can be downloaded at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg463009/.

1. To use WinDbg, you'll need to get the symbols files. Download the symbol files and put them in a local folder.
2. Open up WinDbg. On the File menu, click Symbol File Path.
3. In the Symbol path box, the documentation says to type the following command: SRV*your local folder for symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols, however I just put in the local folder for the symbols and it worked fine.
4. Exit out and open WinDbg again, and Open Crash Dump and locate the dump file that was created by DebugDiag.
5. In the command line, type .loadby sos clr
6. Now type !CLRStack

In the results, it should be clear what the problem is (you'll likely see a BUNCH of lines showing the function(s) that was repeatedly being called).